# How to use multiple URLs from a txt file using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to this and my code runs successfully but only with one URL in the .txt file, if I add more it throws an error. I have tried multiple methods I found on this site but can't seem to find one that works. If anyone can assist me that would be great.

My main objective is for it to look at the first URL, after it has completed, then start the 2nd URL and loop through them.

Here is what I have right now...

```
import requests
import lxml.html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from dhooks import Webhook, Embed

ua = UserAgent()
header = {'user-agent':ua.random}

with open('urls.txt','r') as file:
    for url in file.readlines():
        result = requests.get(url,headers=header,timeout=3)
        src = result.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over them. This code assumes there is one url per line in your file:

```
import requests
import lxml.html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from dhooks import Webhook, Embed

ua = UserAgent()
header = {'user-agent':ua.random}

with open('urls.txt','r') as file:
    for url in file.readlines():
        result = requests.get(url,headers=header,timeout=3)
        src = result.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
```

Comment: I tried this just now, I don't get an error anymore but now it only reads the last line on my .txt

Comment: `file.readlines()` will iterate over all the lines in your file. Print the urls instead of requesting them and see what you are getting. Might be a problem with your urls.txt

Comment: It shows both the URLs I have put in the .txt file, but the scraping only runs for the 2nd URL... weird.

Comment: No it doesn't. You are probably storing the response of the first request in a variable, then overwriting that variable with the response of the second request. All you see if the second response.

Comment: Exactly as I said. You exit the for loop, so the only data contained in the variable `soup` is from the last iteration of the loop. Indent everything below the line where you declare the `soup` variable so that it is within the for loop.

Comment: Sorry, are you able to show me an example of that? As I said, I am new at this :( I tried indenting as you said but I got an error that the indentation is incorrect or that there are too many spaces

Comment: Thanks, I got this error, Bad Request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Documents\Python Course\bsoup.py", line 60, in <module>
    embed.set_author(name=productBrand)
NameError: name 'productBrand' is not defined
[Finished in 0.7s with exit code 1]

Comment: I can't troubleshoot every error in your code in stackoverflow comments. The thread will get flagged and closed. Take some time to thoroughly read the error and it will tell you exactly what the problem is. Please upvote and accept if I answered your original question. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is far too much going on in the code. I'm not sure what the actual issue is? Can you fetch url.txt? If so what does this contain?

As a starting point try separate your code into methods.

For example:

```
import requests
import lxml.html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from dhooks import Webhook, Embed

def getReadMe():
    with open('urls.txt','r') as file:
        return file.read()

def getHtml(readMe):
    ua = UserAgent()
    header = {'user-agent':ua.random}
    response = requests.get(readMe,headers=header,timeout=3)
    response.raise_for_status() # throw error for 4xx & 5xx
    return response.content

readMe = getReadMe()
print(readMe) #TODO: does this output text? If so what is it?
html = getHtml(readMe)
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
# TODO: what is in the response html?
```